# Receiving incorrect rowcount using Python 3 and MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

Here's the code:

```
MarketID = data['Markets'][x]['ID'] # Get from JSON data
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM markets WHERE ID = %s", (MarketID,))
rowCount = cursor.rowcount
print('Rowcount:', rowCount)
```

The problem? The rowcount returned is 1. It should be 0. At the moment, the database is empty. All tables are unpopulated. So how am I getting 1?

Comment: what does `cursor.fetchall()` show you?

Comment: That returns ((0,),)

Comment: So, If the database is empty, count(*) returns 0. That's still a result of 1 row. Does that make sense?

Comment: What's a better way to go about this, then? I want to see if there are any rows that match the condition, and if not, add them.

Comment: don't aggregate the rows. just select them.

Comment: `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM markets WHERE ID = %s", (MarketID,))`?

Comment: That did it. Apparently I misunderstood some sample code when trying to figure this out originally. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. You can write an answer if you want.